# why this code doesn't work i am using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wanna delete the values of the list

```
lists = [12,15,15,15,3,15,1,6,4,7,888,56248]
while len(lists) is True:
    lists.pop()
print(lists)
```

But i got this output :

```
[12, 15, 15, 15, 3, 15, 1, 6, 4, 7, 888, 56248]
```

Comment: `len(lists)` is an integer. An integer is never the same object as the Boolean singleton `True`. Perhaps you meant just `while lists`?

Comment: @Matthias agreed and hammered open. The duplicate is talking about iterating over a list while mutating it. This is simply misunderstanding a conditional.

Comment: You could use `while lists: lists.pop()`. The better solution would be `lists = []`. If it has to be the same list (with the same id) use `lists[:] = []`.

Comment: @Matthias `lists.clear()`

Comment: yes your are right i should put it in bool()

Comment: Fair enough. The faulty conditional is the main problem. And my dupe targets don't apply because he's popping from the end of the list, which is safe to do. Sorry about that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: You're so right. I had a `Coffee not found error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in your conditional

```
while len(lists) is True:
```

`is` checks for identity, not equality.

```
[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]  # True
[1, 2, 3] is [1, 2, 3]  # False, they are two distinct (but equivalent) lists.
```

However even equality would be incorrect here, since

```
42 == True           # False
2 == True            # False
any_nonzero == True  # False
# notably 1 == True
# and     0 == False
# but still (1 is True) == False!
```

You can coerce an integer into a boolean

```
bool(42) == True           # True
bool(2) == True            # True
bool(any_nonzero) == True  # True
```

But it's usually better to just leave the coercion to Python

```
while lists:
    lists.pop()
# or more simply:
# lists = []
```

Comment: yes you are right i forgot . i should put it in  bool() .thank you

Comment: Because `0` means `False` in python, and anything else is true. This means that the code will keep deleting the values until the statement is false (when there are no values in the list).

Comment: @StefanPochmann either will work, but you're right that `while lists` is better. I'll edit

Comment: @AJ123 not anything else. The empty string (`""`) and relevantly empty collections (`[]`, `{}`, `set()`, etc) are also Falsey. `while lists` is definitely the idiomatic approach.

Answer (score -1):

If by "delete" you mean removing the element and reducing the list, you can iterate through a copy of lists with a for loop:

```
for n in lists[:]:
    lists.remove(n)
```

If, instead, you want to have a list of None (or 0) values as long as lists, you can do it like this:

```
newlists = [0] * len(lists)
```

As was suggested in the previous comment.